# Display value of checkbox in textarea

Tags: javascript, checkbox, textarea

I have here a code that will display the value of the checkbox when checked. My problem is I don't know how I will add up all the numbers, that when I checked a checkbox the number or value will display automatically to the text area and when I checked another checkbox it will add up to the first checkbox that I checked and when I checked another checkbox it should also add up from the first two checkbox. How will I do that?

```
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function add_sub(el)
            {
                if (el.checked)
                {
                    var total = el;
                    total.form.elements['type'].value+=el.value;
                }
                else
                {
                    var re=new RegExp('(.*)'+el.value+'(.*)$');
                    el.form.elements['type'].value=el.form.elements['type'].value.replace(re,'$1$2');
                }
            }
            </script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <form name="form1" method=post>
                    <textarea name="type" rows="5" cols="35" onclick="this.focus();this.select();"></textarea><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mis1" id="id1" value="1" onclick="add_sub(this);"><label>1</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mis2" id="id2" value="2" onclick="add_sub(this);"><label>2</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mis6" id="id3" value="3" onclick="add_sub(this);"><label>3</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mis6" id="id4" value="4" onclick="add_sub(this);"><label>4</label>
                </form>
            </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this fiddle if this is what you meant:
http://jsfiddle.net/zyfmt4at/5/

this is the script:

```
var currNum = 0;
var txtArea = document.getElementById("txtArea");
var form = document.getElementById("mainForm");
function add_sub(el){
    debugger;
                if (el.checked)
                {
                    currNum += parseInt(el.value,10);
                }
                else
                {
                    currNum -= parseInt(el.value,10);
                }
                txtArea.value = currNum;
}

form.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
    if(ev.target.getAttribute("type") == "checkbox"){
        add_sub(ev.target);
    }
},false);
```

this is the HTML:

```
    <body>
        <form id="mainForm" name="form1" method=post>
            <textarea id="txtArea" name="type" rows="5" cols="35" onclick="this.focus();"></textarea><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mis1" id="id1" value="1"><label>1</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mis2" id="id2" value="2"><label>2</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mis6" id="id3" value="3"><label>3</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mis6" id="id4" value="4"><label>4</label>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions proposed above are based on an assumption that the checkbox values are numbers, in case you are in need of string values. You may suggest this.

```
function add_sub(el)
{

  var cbs = document.getElementById('checkboxes').getElementsByTagName('input');
  var textareaValue = '';  
  for (var i = 0, len = cbs.length; i<len; i++) {
    if ( cbs[i].type === 'checkbox' && cbs[i].checked) {
          textareaValue += cbs[i].value + ' ';
    }
  }

   document.getElementById('textarea').value = textareaValue;            
}
```

and

```
<textarea id="textarea" name="type" rows="5" cols="35" onclick="this.focus();this.select();"></textarea><br>
<div id="checkboxes">
     <input type="checkbox" name="mis1" id="id1" value="1" onclick="add_sub(this);"><label>1</label><br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="mis2" id="id2" value="2" onclick="add_sub(this);"><label>2</label><br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="mis6" id="id3" value="3" onclick="add_sub(this);"><label>3</label><br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="mis6" id="id4" value="4" onclick="add_sub(this);"><label>4</label>
</div>
```

And the working plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/HWHRsBn7s7vJ9KI4UauU

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

- Don't listen to `click` events to detect changes in checboxes. They can change in other ways, e.g. with the keyboard. You can listen to `change` events instead.
- Don't use event handler content attributes in the HTML source. Add event listeners using JS.
- Don't add the same event listener to all events. Delegate it to a common ancestor instead.
- `br` elements are ugly. Better use `display: block`.

```js
var sum = 0,
    form = document.forms.form1,
    text = form1.elements.type;
text.addEventListener('focus', text.select.bind(text));
form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if(e.target.type == 'checkbox') {
    sum += e.target.value * (e.target.checked ? 1 : -1);
    text.value = sum;
  }
});
```

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post">
  <textarea name="type" rows="5" cols="35">0</textarea>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mis1" id="id1" value="1">1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mis2" id="id2" value="2">2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mis6" id="id3" value="3">3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mis6" id="id4" value="4">4</label>
</form>
```